# Change Parameter Value of Expression<Func<<string>>

Tags: c#, .net, expression, expression-trees, func

Let's say I've got the class Item which looks like this

```
public class Item
{
    // ..
    Expression<Func<string>> Callback {get; set;}
}
```

`Item` defines a property called `Callback` which can be used like this

```
public string TestFunction(string ident, DateTime value1, DateTime value2)
{
    return string.Join(";", ident, value1, value2);
}

// ..

Item x = new Item();

x.Callback = () => TestFunction("Hello there", DateTime.Now.Date, DateTime.Now);

Console.WriteLine(x.Callback.Compile().Invoke()); // prints the expected output
```

That works just well. Now, what I'm trying to do is change the value of the `DateTime` parameters.

I've already figured out how to get the arguments:

```
MethodCallExpression body = (MethodCallExpression)x.Callback.Body;

foreach(ConstantExpression arg in body.Arguments) {
    if(arg.Type == typeof(DateTime)) {
        //arg.Value =  => READONLY!
    }
}
```

However, I can't assign a new value to `arg.Value` because doesn't have a setter.

There seems to be something called `ExpressionVisitor` but I'm unsure if that's something I need.

Is there any way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Thank you in advance

__

**Update**

I almost got it working with @Guru Stron help but there's still a small problem.

This piece of code works perfectly fine:

```
var newParams = new[] { Expression.Constant("testIdent"), Expression.Constant(DateTime.Now), Expression.Constant(DateTime.Now) };
```

However, the following code throws an

```
Expression of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.ConstantExpression' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.String' of method 'System.String TestFunction(System.String, System.DateTime, System.DateTime)'
```

Exception.

```
List<ConstantExpression> para = new List<ConstantExpression>();

foreach (var arg in body.Arguments) {
    if (arg.Type == typeof(DateTime)) {
        para.Add(Expression.Constant(DateTime.Now));
        continue;
    }

    para.Add(Expression.Constant(arg));
}

var exprBody = Expression.Call(body.Object, body.Method, para); // Exception is thrown here
```

The error is pretty obvious but I can't seem to find a way to convert the parameter to the correct type.

The reason why I changed the code is because I don't know the amount of parameters, so I tried to loop through them any only change the ones I need since the order remains correct.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to build a new expression and pass new desired parameters to it:

```
MethodCallExpression body = (MethodCallExpression)x.Callback.Body;
var newParams = new[] { Expression.Constant("NEW "), Expression.Constant(DateTime.Now), Expression.Constant(DateTime.Now)};
var exprBody = Expression.Call(body.Object, body.Method, newParams );
var newExpr = Expression.Lambda<Func<string>>(exprBody);
var newFunc = newExpr.Compile();
Console.WriteLine(newFunc()); // "NEW ;03-Jun-20 5:07:16 PM;03-Jun-20 5:07:16 PM"
```

Comment: @Shawn was glad to help!

Comment: Just out of interest: Are calls like ```.Compile``` being cached? I remember that certain calls in the Reflection Environment will be cached so maybe that's the same case here.

Comment: @Shawn AFAIK no, you will need to cache them yourself.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I actually ran into a new problem, I've updated the post. Can you take a look at that as well?

Comment: @Shawn changing `para`  to  `var para = new List<Expression>();` and `para.Add(Expression.Constant(arg));` to `para.Add(arg);`

Comment: Oh, yeah. Of course, should've seen that :D Thanks, it works well now!